# 2000 mercedes e320

Tags: engine, overheating, mercedes-benz

My car keeps shutting down after 10 Mins driving 20 to 30 min of sit time and were on the road again. Temp gauge reads hot but engines not hot nor is the coolant.the fan works if I hookup to a battery direct buy not when I connect to the car with it . Does anyone know What should do??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

We'd like to understand what's going on.  Could be a temperature sender problem or a fan controller issue.  Its a whole lot easier to work this problem if we know the exact temperatures involved (°F or °C).

Do you have access to an OnBoard Diagnostic (OBD) II troubleshooting tool? You need a decent tool, one that goes beyond just reading stored codes.  We're going to want to look at the engine temperature during your drive cycle.

With that said, it sounds like your vehicle has a thermo controlled electric cooling fan.  Cooling fans are particularly important for a vehicle that is stopped.  Generally the input to a fan controller is temperature and possibly air conditioning switch input. Normally these controllers are Pulse Width Modulation (PWM) devices.  That allows the cooling fan motor to run at variable speeds, using less power to improve fuel economy where possible.

At first glance it would seem either the temperature sender is not working correctly, or the fan controller is not working correctly.  You will know that within ten minutes after plugging in the OBDII tool and go for a drive.  If the temp sender is working correctly, you'd just replace the cooling motor controller.  If the temp sender is not reading correctly, you'd replace it, and retest the vehicle.

A BlueTooth or Wifi enabled OBDII sender is pretty inexpensive.  [Typically as cheap as $15 or $20 USD.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071YC1J7R) Obviously that type of sender will require a smart phone, but basic software is free.